Can we construct an adversary that learns a single bit of the plaintext if we have access to a "successful" EAV adversary?
We know that if a scheme is EAV-secure then for all Probabilistic Polynomial-time adversaries $A$, $A$ can learn a single bit of the plaintext given its ciphertext with negligible probability only.
The proof given in Katz and Lindell (theorem 3.10) is simple and relies on constructing an adversary that breaks EAV-security if we have access to an PPT adversary that can correctly guess a single bit of the plaintext.
My question is if we can go the other way. That is, if we can construct an adversary that can learn a single bit of the plaintext if we are given access to an adversary that can break EAV-security.

No, we cannot:

If the encryption scheme is public-key (which implies that the adversary has always access to an "encryption oracle"), then EAV security necessarily requires a randomized encryption procedure (if encryption is deterministic, breaking EAV is an easy exercise).
"Every single bit is hard to predict given an encryption of a
random plaintext" is a one-wayness property that can be achieved for
deterministic encryption schemes. Any deterministic public-key encryption scheme with this property will be a counter-example of what you are looking
for (as the scheme will admit a trivial EAV adversary). Note that a PKE is in particular a secret-key encryption scheme.

A concrete counter-example is given by RSA encryption $m \to m^e \bmod N$. The classical paper of Håstad and Nåslund shows that every single bit of a random plaintext encrypted with RSA is hard to predict (assuming that the RSA assumption holds), yet RSA is deterministic, hence not EAV secure.

Thanks for your answer.  I'm not at the point in my journey where I can even understand it, unfortunately, but I will come back to it.
